# How do you make a ShapeRenderer always full screen on resize?

Tags: libgdx

I have:

```
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(stage.getViewport().getCamera().combined);
```

And I tried to do the following in `render()`:

```
shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, stage.getViewport().getScreenWidth(), stage.getViewport.getScreenHeight());
```

Which full-screens the `ShapeRenderer` when I first run my project, but as soon as I resize the window, the rectangle starts to change size and go off-screen. I'm using a `FitViewport` on my `Stage`, is there any way to make the `ShapeRenderer` always be full screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the methods `getWorldWidth` and `getWorldHeight` instead of the `screen` counterparts. "World" is the emulated size of the viewport while "screen" is your actual screen size.

Comment: Lucky call? You should actually give it the matrix you want to draw to. So if you have a camera for viewing the map and want to use `shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatric(worldCamera.combined)`. If you want to use it on your fixed screen gui that's using the stage then getting the camera from the stage is perfectly fine. Just make sure you use `resize()` properly.

Comment: @Madmenyo They _are_ setting the projection matrix (read: `shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(stage.getViewport().getCamera().combined);`). And that is exactly why it's the wrong size. They cannot use the size of the _screen_ since that is not in sync with the size of the _viewport_ unless the viewport is a `ScreenViewport`.